# Crossover method for 3D velocity vector genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms, physics

I am trying to write a genetic algorithm which will learn how to throw a ball at a target. I have successfully implemented code that will graph the projectile motion of a sphere given an input velocity vector $u(0)$.

However, I'm not really sure about the crossover part. Right now, I am selecting the parents using a distribution whereby their chance of being picked is equal to $\dfrac{i}{\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}}$ where $i = n - p$ where $p$ is the individual's position in the population when sorted by fitness from best to worst and $n$ is the number of individuals in the population. Then I randomly pick $n$ individuals from the population according to this distribution, and I take individuals $n_i$ and $n_{i+1}$ as parents. Then I make a child $c = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{u_{x_i}(t) + u_{x_{i+1}}(t)}{2} \\ \dfrac{u_{y_i}(t) + u_{y_{i+1}}(t)}{2} \\ \dfrac{u_{z_i}(t) + u_{z_{i+1}}(t)}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and keep repeating this until I have a new population filled with $n$ children.

After $51$ generations, my sphere hit one point specified point on the plane. However, I don't think this is the most effective crossover method and I would really appreciate some suggestions on how to improve it.

Sorry if my notation or explanation is unclear, please ask me to explain it if it is not evident what I mean.